# How to use Regex if there are cases of blanks not space

Tags: python, regex

Been trying to get the following:

```
[('08/03/2019', '', '58', '71', '162', '', '1', '71.68', '69.03', '441381.64', '2829.37', '14', '1', '226', '2', '224', '62', '271')]
```

Which works if there is no blanks between the numbers. It originally looks like this:

```
'08/03/2019     175   58   71  162|    5     1| 71.68 69.03|  441381.64    2829.37|   14     1|  226    2  224   62|   271|'

[('08/03/2019', '175', '58', '71', '162', '5', '1', '71.68', '69.03', '441381.64', '2829.37', '14', '1', '226', '2', '224', '62', '271')]
```

Script used :

```
re.compile(r"([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})\s{5}(\d+)\s{3}(\d+)\s{3}(\d+)\s{2}(\d+)[|]\s{4}(\d+)\s{5}(\d+)[|]\s{1}(\d+[.]\d+)\s{1}(\d+[.]\d+)[|]\s{2}(\d+[.]\d+)\s{4}(\d+[.]\d+)[|]\s{3}(\d+)\s{5}(\d+)[|]\s{2}(\d+)\s{4}(\d+)\s{2}(\d+)\s{3}(\d+)[|]\s{3}(\d+)")
```

The problem comes when blanks appear in the original data set, for example, where 175 and 5 are missing the re.compile script does not pick up the number:

```
'08/03/2019        58   71  162|         1| 71.68 69.03|  441381.64    2829.37|   14     1|  226    2  224   62|   271|'
```

Doing a split with `(\s+)` or `\s+` does not help as the space pattern differs (`5,3,3,2,4,5,1,1,2,4,3,5,2,4,2,3,3` would be the spaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you have designed looks great, you might just want to add a `?` after those capturing groups that might have missing values, and it would likely solve the problem, you are facing now.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B55tBk/1/)

Here for instance, we would add two `?`:

```
import re

expression = r"([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4})\s{5}(\d+)?\s{3}(\d+)\s{3}(\d+)\s{2}(\d+)[|]\s{4}(\d+)?\s{5}(\d+)[|]\s{1}(\d+[.]\d+)\s{1}(\d+[.]\d+)[|]\s{2}(\d+[.]\d+)\s{4}(\d+[.]\d+)[|]\s{3}(\d+)\s{5}(\d+)[|]\s{2}(\d+)\s{4}(\d+)\s{2}(\d+)\s{3}(\d+)[|]\s{3}(\d+)"

string = """
08/03/2019        58   71  162|         1| 71.68 69.03|  441381.64    2829.37|   14     1|  226    2  224   62|   271|

08/03/2019     175   58   71  162|    5     1| 71.68 69.03|  441381.64    2829.37|   14     1|  226    2  224   62|   271|

"""


print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
[('08/03/2019', '', '58', '71', '162', '', '1', '71.68', '69.03', '441381.64', '2829.37', '14', '1', '226', '2', '224', '62', '271'), ('08/03/2019', '175', '58', '71', '162', '5', '1', '71.68', '69.03', '441381.64', '2829.37', '14', '1', '226', '2', '224', '62', '271')]
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/B55tBk/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/B55tBk/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Hi @Emma,  I'm trying to get in cases where 175 and 5 are not present. Is there a way to maintain the same spacing?

Comment: Hi @Emma, Not sure if it answers the question where 71 is missing instead, the raw data is kind of tricky as the blanks are inconsistent and only the spaces in between are. Thank you.